What were the SPA/EPA (Start/End of Guarded Area) control characters used for?
While looking through the documentation for xterm, I noticed that it listed ESC V and ESC W as Start of Guarded Area (SPA  is 0x96) and End of Guarded Area (EPA  is 0x97) respectively, but didn't say what a "guarded area" was.
Places like aivosto.com's Control characters in ASCII and Unicode describe SPA as "Starts a string of character positions that can't be altered manually or transmitted. Optionally protects against erasure too. EPA will end the string." but I found that confusing in the context of something like xterm, which is emulating a device which, you'd think, would only ever encounter those control codes by having them transmitted.
Initially, I was wondering if maybe they were the terminal emulator equivalent to those flags in PDFs which instruct the PDF reader to disallow copying, editing, and/or printing the document's contents, meant to prevent employees from using locally attached printers to perform corporate espionage.
DuckDuckGo and Google turned out to be almost useless for finding an answer myself and, in the end, I wound up having to go direct to the mentioned ANSI X3.64-1979 and ECMA-48 to get the details, which made this a self-answer for the benefit of others.

From ANSI X3.64-1979, it becomes apparent that, along with SSA (Start of Selected Area) and ESA (End of Selected Area), they're part of a system for describing forms to block-oriented terminals.
More specifically, ANSI X3.64-1979 defines two separate ways to do the same thing.

As a convenience to implementors the frequently encountered concept of protected and selected areas has been provided in both a simple form utilizing a single character (SPA, EPA, SSA, and ESA) and in the more general Define Area Qualification (DAQ) framework as well. The intent is that they provide equivalent functionality. However, interaction between the two forms is not specified in this standard.

SPA and EPA provide a simple way to define text that should neither be sent to an "auxiliary device" (eg. when saving/loading form contents via a local card/tape punch) nor be editable by the user (i.e. stuff like form field labels), while DAQ is what people think of when they read the Wikipedia description of a block terminal's capabilities, and provides a much richer language, though with more of a learning curve, for describing forms, including restrictions analogous to HTML5's client-side validation features for <input> tags.
This also helps to explain why the names "Start of Guarded Area" and "End of Guarded Area" used by both Unicode's U0080.pdf and xterm aren't technically wrong, even if they disagree with the "Start of Protected Area" and "End of Protected Area" names ANSI X3.64-1979 gave them... they define a "guarded protected area".

B8.2 Protected and Guarded Areas
A protected area is a special case of a qualified area. It is a string of character positions, the contents of which are protected against manual alteration. Another special type of a qualified area is a guarded area. It is a protected area to be excluded from transmission of a data stream and from transfer to an auxiliary input/output device. A protected area may, in general, be either
guarded or unguarded. The control characters SPA (Start of Protected Area) and EPA (End of Protected Area) provide
an alternative to DAQ for establishing the beginning and end of a guarded protected area.

This is all affected by a system of modes which controls things like whether the terminal will return the contents of the field currently containing the cursor or the contents of all fields when the user's action causes the displayed data to be submitted for processing.
...now maybe the next person in my situation can have a useful search result pop up.

They were a way to move certain features of terminal systems over to less complex single control code protocols. Like embedding control information or suppress menu elements when doinga print out using a terminals hard copy function. Yes, some terminal handling is outright weird and can only be explained by history. Then again real Block Mode terminals are way more complex. Still, some early (non IBM) ASCII based terminals with block mode used similar characters to create their forms.

It might be also useful to know that those codes (and some other) are depending on modes set (SM), like GATM to define transmission. All together they were an attempt to somehow move the way (IBMish) block mode terminals  work into the ASCII/stream world. Be aware, it's a deep, deep rat-hole to follow. ECMA-48 describes at best the surface texture :))

I did see the part about the modes, and it was even in one of my earlier drafts... but I got the impression that, if I put the same amount of polish into covering them, I'd find another thing that should probably also get covered until I'd eventually summarized the entire standard. Stopping here answers the initial question while providing hopefully enough context for people who are still curious to pick up one of the linked specs and keep reading. ...I will make a quick tweak though.

No need to add much.As mentioned, it's a very deep hole and even worse, the standard does not really explain anything. At least not in a way that one would be able to do an implementation using what's provided. At best all info therein isa guideline for someone already knowing what he has to implement and just look up to who parts can be used. At best I'd remove that HTML comparison and and some words about them being part of a way more complex but not fully spelled out interaction/definition.

AFAIK DEC terminals never supported this (and thus, most current terminal emulators don't support it either). The VT131/VT132 have a proprietary control sequence (DECPRO) to make all characters with a determinate rendition protected (none, bold, underline, blink, reverse, normal), but apparently it didn't have much success, and didn't appear in later terminals. From the VT220 there is a different set of sequences (DECSCA, DECSEL, DECSED) just to make characters protected from deletion. Support for DECSCA in modern terminal emulators is not that widespread.

Ann Arbor XL series terminals (Genie, Ambassador, Guru) supported SPA/EPA/DAQ.  So I believe did Visual Technology Visual 400, LSI ADM 36 (limited support), Teleray 16, Wicat T7000, Beehive ATL-008, Prime PT250. Also implemented by the US military's IISS (Integrated Information Support System) but not sure what hardware they used. And I know some contemporary terminal emulators implement DQA – in particular Intermec ITE/TE 2000, Honeywell RFTerm, LXE ANSI Plus. Maybe it isn't a coincidence that they are all somewhat obscure products targeted at industrial automation applications.
